# How to implement ASP.NET Core Web API Basic Authentication using SQL Server database without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

In my ASP.NET Core Web API I have a basic authentication handler defined in `BasicAuthenticationHandler.cs` like this:

```
using MyAPI.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text;

namespace MyAPI.Data
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock, IUserRepository userRepository) :
           base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _userRepository = userRepository;
        }

        protected async override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            var authorizationHeader = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.StartsWith("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var token = authorizationHeader.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
                var credentialsAsEncodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(token));
                var credentials = credentialsAsEncodedString.Split(':');

                if (await _userRepository.Authenticate(credentials[0], credentials[1]))
                {
                    var claims = new[] { new Claim("name", credentials[0]), new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin") };
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Basic");
                    var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(claimsPrincipal, Scheme.Name)));
                }
            }

            Response.StatusCode = 401;
            Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\".com\"");

            return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header"));
        }
    }
}
```

`IUserRepository` is this:

```
using MyAPI.Models;

namespace MyAPI.Interfaces
{
    public interface IUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IUserRepository
    {
        Task<bool> Authenticate(string username, string password);
    }
}
```

This is `User.cs`:

```
using MyAPI.Interfaces;

namespace MyAPI.Models
{
    public class User : IUser
    {
        private string _username;
        private string _password;

        public User()
        {
            _username = String.Empty;
            _password = String.Empty;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get => _username; set => _username = value; }
        public string Password { get => _password; set => _password = value; }
    }
}
```

Here's my `UserRepository`:

```
using MyAPI.Interfaces;

namespace MyAPI.Models
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private List<User> _users = new List<User>
        {
            new User
            {
                Id = 1, Username = "user1", Password = "password1"
            },
            new User
            {
                Id = 2, Username = "user2", Password = "password2"
            }
        };

        public async Task<bool> Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            if (await Task.FromResult(_users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password)) != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And in `Program.cs`, I have this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("BasicAuthentication")
                .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>("BasicAuthentication", null);
```

This works perfectly well for the given hard-code users, but now I want to have the `List<User>` to be filled from a database table, without using Entity Framework.

I have an `appsettings.json` file containing this connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Users": "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Users;Trusted_Connection=True;"
},
```

but I have no `DbContext` descendent. Nor do I want one.

What I want to do, at some point in `Program.cs`, is load the records from the `Users.dbo.UserList` table into the `List<User>` property of the `UserRepository` instead of using the locally initialised version, but I just can't seem to work out the dependency injections, the scopes, or the initialisations for it to work.

EDIT 31/3

Based on Jerry's answer, I updated `UserRepository.cs` to this:

```
using MyAPI.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace MyAPI.Models
{
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        public List<User> Users = new();

        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly string _connectionstring;

        public UserRepository(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _connectionstring = _configuration.GetConnectionString("Users") ?? string.Empty;

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = new(_connectionstring))
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM UserList";
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                var user = new User();

                                user.UserNo = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                user.UserName = reader.GetString(1).Trim();
                                user.Password = reader.GetString(2).Trim();

                                Users.Add(user);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore it for now
                // throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> Authenticate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (await Task.FromResult(
                Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName.Equals(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.Password.Equals(password, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            ) != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This includes DI for the configuration to get the connection string and works fine. The only downside is that the constructor for `UserRepository` is called for every API request, which is a lot of database activity when the API is in heavy use.

What I intend to do is have a single API method for generating a token that uses Basic Authentication, and for all other methods to use Bearer Token Authentication instead. The token will have a set lifetime, after which Basic Authentication has to be used again to create a new token.

Comment: So you're looking for something like https://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `UserRepository.cs` like below. It reads the database without efcore and initialize the value of `_user` in construct function.

```
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        private List<User> _users = new List<User>
        {
        };
        public UserRepository()
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=192.168.2.68;Database=Users;User Id=sa;Password=xxxxx;"))
            {
                connection.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT * FROM UserList";
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            _users.Add(new User { Id = reader.GetInt32(0), Username = reader.GetString(1), Password = reader.GetString(2) });
                        }
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        public async Task<bool> Authenticate(string username, string password)
        {
            if (await Task.FromResult(_users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username && x.Password == password)) != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

My testing database is like
[image]